# Grails Spring Security UI MySQL all users disabled?

Tags: mysql, grails, spring-security

I am using Grails 2.1.1 with Spring Security 1.2.7.1 and Spring Security UI 0.2.

When I create some test users in BootStrap.groovy using an in memory database I am able to log in and manage users--everything works fine. However, when I switch my data source to a MySQL database, the service states that the user account is disabled when I try to log in. I have checked and the password appears to be hashing correctly (i.e., it matches what's in the database). The only modification I made to a user is to include a Study ID. In attempting to debug the code I've found that org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser indicates enabled=false.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

My DataSource:

```
    dataSource {
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/users"
        username = "root"
        password = ""
        dbCreate = "create-drop" 
    }
```

My BootStrap.groovy code:

```
    def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
    def userRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)

    def testAdmin = new User(username: 'me', enabled: true, password: 'password', studyID: '0')
    testAdmin.save(flush: true)
    UserRole.create testAdmin, adminRole, true

    def testUser = new User(username: '100', enabled: true, password: 'test', studyID: '101')
    testUser.save(flush: true)
    UserRole.create testUser, userRole, true

    assert User.count() == 2
    assert Role.count() == 2
    assert UserRole.count() == 2
```

A row from my User.user table after starting the application. No matter how I change these values, login attempts state that the user is disabled:

```
id  version account_expired account_locked  enabled password    password_expired    studyid username
        1   0   1   1   1   5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a...   1   0   me
```

Comment: Does it really says that the account is 'disabled'? Because the row you posted says that the account expired, is locked and the password expired too. You cannot log in with those values set to true.

Comment: Yes. I am getting "Sorry, your account is disabled." I have tried manually changing the accout_expired/account_locked/password_expired fields in the database for the user, but it makes no difference. The error is being thrown in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks from public void check(UserDetails user) ...   if (!user.isEnabled()) {
   log.debug("User account is disabled");

   throw new DisabledException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.disabled",
    "User is disabled"), user);
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If making changes directly into the DB also gives the error and it works with the 'in memory DB', I think that MySQL might be the problem.

It can be that MySQL is storing the values using a type that Hibernate cannot use correctly as a `boolean`

You can test that by retrieving a user from the DB and manually check:

```
if( ! user.enabled ) println "not enabled"  // or something like that
```

The last 3 posts on [this mail list](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Boolean-not-saving-correctly-BIT-1-saves-any-boolean-as-b-td1328443.html) give a solution to correctly map a `boolean` in MySQL:

You can use a custom dialect to change BIT(1) to boolean:

```
   import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect 
   import java.sql.Types 

   class MyCustomMySQL5InnoDBDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect { 
      MyCustomMySQL5InnoDBDialect() { 
         registerColumnType(Types.BIT, 'boolean') 
      } 
   }
```

And use it specify the class in DataSource.groovy:

```
   dataSource { 
      pooled = true 
      driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' 
      username = ... 
      password = ... 
      dialect = com.foo.bar.MyCustomMySQL5InnoDBDialect 
   }
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for the help. Posting solution here.